# Need OSX terminal application that can save file as non-binary

Tags: macos, iterm2

I am currently using Sublime Text 3 and iTerm2.  Whenever I save a log from iTerm2, it contains characters that indicate things like backspaces and such.  These characters make the file non-searchable (with find in files) in Sublime.  Is anyone aware of a terminal application that will not store these keypresses in logs, or a way to prevent iTerm2 from storing these keypresses?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the backspaces out *after* saving it.  That aspect has been discussed several times.  For example

- *[Can I programmatically “burn in” ANSI control codes to a file using unix utils?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269278/can-i-programmatically-burn-in-ansi-control-codes-to-a-file-using-unix-utils/28334291#28334291)*
- *[format output from Unix “script” command: remove backspaces, linefeeds and deleted chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7152339/format-output-from-unix-script-command-remove-backspaces-linefeeds-and-delet)*